# Perl print message

Tags: perl

My problem is, how can I print the message, see or check out my code.

Heres the code...

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use LWP::UserAgent;

my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new( timeout => 1 );
$ua->agent("007");

my $req = HTTP::Request->new( GET => 'http://www.google.com.ph/' );

my $res;
for ( 1 .. 10 ) {
    $res = $ua->request($req);
    if ( $res->is_success ) {
        print "+ Server is ok!\n";
    }
    else {
        print "- Server is not ok!\n";
        last;
    }
    sleep 1;
}

# How to show this message if "- Server is not ok!\n".
# Example: perl test.pl
# + Server is ok!
# + Server is ok!
# + Server is ok!
# + Server is ok!
# + Server is ok!
# + Server is ok!
# - Server is not ok!
# Your server is not ok, please check!
# 
print "Your server is not ok, please check!\n";

# And how to show this message if 10 reply is "+ Server is ok!\n".
# Example: perl test.pl
# + Server is ok!
# + Server is ok!
# + Server is ok!
# + Server is ok!
# + Server is ok!
# + Server is ok!
# + Server is ok!
# + Server is ok!
# + Server is ok!
# + Server is ok!
# Your server is ok, Congrats!
# 
print "Your server is ok, Congrats!\n";
```

How to show this message if `- Server is not ok!\n`.

Example: perl test.pl

- Server is ok!
- Server is ok!
- Server is ok!
- Server is ok!
- Server is ok!
- Server is ok!
- Server is not ok!

Your server is not ok, please check!

And how to show this message if 10 reply is "+ Server is ok!\n".

Example: perl test.pl

- Server is ok!
- Server is ok!
- Server is ok!
- Server is ok!
- Server is ok!
- Server is ok!
- Server is ok!
- Server is ok!
- Server is ok!
- Server is ok!

Your server is ok, Congrats!

Thanks in advance for someone will fix my problem in perl script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can output the message before jumping with `last`. But in more complex situations, you can introduce a "flag" variable:

```
my $ok = 1;
```

Before `last`, set it to zero:

```
$ok = 0;
```

At the very end, use it to determine the message:

```
if ($ok) {
    print "Your server is ok, Congrats!\n";
} else {
    print "Your server is not ok, please check!\n";
}
```

Comment: Ok, I got it! Thanks for this solution. My script now ok. :)